# Command-line tool to speed up an MP3 that contains speech

Tags: windows, audio, command-line, mp3

What the best command-line tool that runs on Windows to speed up MP3s? A tool that I give an mp3 (or wav) and that returns an mp3.

Comment: Do you want to *play* or *edit+save* them via command-line?

Comment: @unor: Edit+save

Answer (score 5):

You can use [SoX (Sound eXchange)](http://sox.sourceforge.net/):

- free
- open source
- Windows / Linux / Mac
- CLI
- can speed up MP3s: e.g. `sox --show-progress in.mp3 out.mp3 speed 2`. You may want to change the pitch as well, e.g. `sox --show-progress in.mp3 out.mp3 speed 2 pitch -200`. You can otherwise use `stretch` to change the rate of playback of an audio sample while preserving the pitch. For example to x2 speed a file: `sox --show-progress in.mp3 out.mp3 stretch 0.5`

FYI: [SoX manual](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html).

Comment: I would prefer if the tool would automatically change the pitch to the correct value as well. Otherwise how do I know the correct pitch adjustment?

Comment: @Christian Answer edited, example with `stretch` added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Paulstretch](http://hypermammut.sourceforge.net/paulstretch/) (a.k.a. Paul's Extreme Sound Stretch):

- free
- Open-Source (version 2 of the General Public License)
- source code for Linux or the Windows binaries available
- [CPP](https://github.com/paulnasca/paulstretch_cpp) and [Python](https://github.com/paulnasca/paulstretch_python) versions available. The Python version provides a CLI.

Description from the website:

> - It produces high quality extreme sound stretching. While most sound stretching software sounds bad when trying to stretch the sounds a
>     lot, this one is optimized for extreme sound stretching. So, the
>     stretch amount is unlimited.
> - You can play the stretched sound in real-time (including the possibility to "freeze" the sound) or you can render the whole sound
>     or a part of it to audio files
> - It has many post-processing effects, like: filters, pitch/frequency shifters
> - Support for WAV, OGG VORBIS files and MP3 files

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]